# Not Able to HTTP Request from iOS/Android Simulator(IONIC/Capacitor) to node/express backend

Tags: express, ionic-framework, nuxt.js, capacitor

I'm trying to make a mobile app using Nuxtjs, Ionic, Capacitor and Nodejs/Express.

I was able to check that my nuxtapp is able to send a http request to the express app with the cors settings.

However, when I try to send a request from the ios simulator or the android emulator, there is no response coming back.

I already had a look at this article from ionic [Cors Issues](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors#solutions-for-cors-errors), but I only see response when running nuxt command.

I've also checked by running this curl command:

```
curl -H "Origin: capacitor://localhost" --head http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tours/
```

and I see 200 OK response.

Is there anything I am missing? I would appreciate any of your thoughts.

Here is my code for express:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const hpp = require('hpp');
const cors = require('cors');

const AppError = require('./utils/appError');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController');
const tourRouter = require('./routes/tourRoutes');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const reviewRouter = require('./routes/reviewRoutes');

const app = express();

// 1) GLOBAL MIDDLEWARES
// Set security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// CORS Setting

const allowedOrigins = [
  'capacitor://localhost',
  'ionic://localhost',
  'http://localhost',
  'http://localhost:8080',
  'http://localhost:8100',
  'http://localhost:3000'
];

// Reflect the origin if it's in the allowed list or not defined (cURL, Postman, etc.)
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin) || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Origin not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  }
};

// Enable preflight requests for all routes
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: 'This route is CORS-enabled for an allowed origin.' });
});

// Development logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!'
});
app.use('/api', limiter);

// Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());

// Prevent parameter pollution
app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: [
      'duration',
      'ratingsQuantity',
      'ratingsAverage',
      'maxGroupSize',
      'difficulty',
      'price'
    ]
  })
);

// Serving static files
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

// Test middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  // console.log(req.headers);
  next();
});

// 3) ROUTES
app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviewRouter);

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

This is how i am sending a request from Nuxt:

```
ion-button(color="success" @click="onClick") Success

methods: {
    async onClick() {
    await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tours/').then(response => {
        this.tours = response.data.doc
    })
},
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know express part but I hope can help for ionic part. Maybe you should use HttpClient for this. Axios is not working right for ionic. Check this out :> 

https://github.com/capacitor-community/http

Comment: Emire Akbaki Thanks for your reply. I've tried your approach using the package from capacitor, but I still get no response when clicking the button. Is anyone having the same issue with other framework?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution for this is to use SPA mode for NuxtJS.
The http request to the backend worked.

The downside for not using NuxtJS SSR is that it is not good for SEOs and the initial build time can be very slow if the project side is large. However these two factors don't matter when making mobile applications with Ionic and Capacitor because mobile apps a built during downloads.